# filling the missing data

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes

```
df_1:

ID    |  title  |  name   |   age
----------------------------------
32    |  AA     | Alex    | 30
----------------------------------
4568  |  BB     |  Dom    |  35
----------------------------------
3804  |  CC     |  pascal |  58
----------------------------------




  df_2:


ID   |  title   
--------------
288  |  AZERTY    
--------------
290  |  querty      
--------------
```

I want to append the data of the `df_2` to `df_1`. And I want to fill the column age by `right` in front the line coming from `df_1`.

df_1 to be:

```
ID    |  title  |  name   |   age
----------------------------------
32    |  AA     | Alex    | 30
----------------------------------
4568  |  BB     |  Dom    |  35
----------------------------------
3804  |  CC     |  pascal |  58
----------------------------------
288  |  AZERTY  | right   | right
-----------------------------------
290  |  querty  | right   | right    
-----------------------------------
```

How can I append the dataframes in `pyspark` with filling the missing columns ?

Comment: Merge works too, need to add columns prior to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to union tables:

```
df_2 = df_2
  .withColumn("name", lit("right"))
  .withColumn("age", lit("right"))

df_1.union(df_2).show()

+----+------+-------+-------+
|  id| title|   name|    age|
+----+------+-------+-------+
|  32|    AA|   Alex|     30|
|4568|    BB|    Dom|     35|
| 288|AZERTY|right  |right  |
| 290|querty|right  |right  |
+----+------+-------+-------+
```